# How to convert a typo3 plugin extension into an backend module extension?

Tags: typo3, backend

I have still problems to run an backend module for typo3 10. I found following extension, which works fine as a plugin.https://github.com/helhum/upload_example Now I want it to run it as a backend module to check if it works that way.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you could describe what you want to achieve on your backend module. Do you want to just upload some photos or do you want to build relations between files and objects? Or something else?

Comment: I want to upload some Fotos at first. I am about to build an PDF Genertor, which does not work jet. It is a step to achive functionality

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in functionality to upload photos in the filelist and use the files there for your backend module? Don't build things you still have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the goal here is to just upload some photos via the a backend Module. Assuming that you already have a Module and an action for it, for example **indexAction** (if not, here is how to create a module: [Backend Module](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/BackendModules/Index.html)) here is what you can do.

> Keep in mind, this is the most basic example i could think of. Validations and various other actions have to be taken into consideration based on your needs.

**HTML**

```
<f:form action="upload" controller="YourController" name="files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Select a file</label>
          <f:form.textfield name="file" type="file" class="form-control" id="formFile"/>
     </div>
     <f:form.submit value="File upload" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</f:form>
```

This example is for one file but you can convert it to multiple as well by using the `multiple` attribute on the input. Nevertheless, nothing special here. A simple form with one field that selects a file(s). Remember: TYPO3 uses Bootstrap, so you can just copy paste the code so you can have a nice form.

**UploadAction**

We defined on which action will the upload take place and in this case is the **uploadAction**. What you need to do here, is to get the form arguments and do something with them, like validating if they are images or csv or any other file kind.

```
public function uploadAction(): void
{
   $fileRequest = $this->request->getArguments()['file'];
   
}
```

This will give you the values inside the 'file' arguments.

> Be careful! The **file** arguments must have a specific structure for
> the upload to work. It should look like this

```
array [
  name => 'filename.csv' (13 chars)
  type => 'text/csv' (8 chars)
  tmp_name => '/tmp/phphwRQXQ' (14 chars)
  error => 0 (integer)
  size => 62505 (integer)
]
```

The next step is to actually save the file. I am using Dependency Injection but for the sake of this answer, i will just use the **GeneralUtility::makeInstance** variant.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory;

public function uploadAction(): void
{
   $fileRequest = $this->request->getArguments()['file'];
   
   $resourceFactory = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ResourceFactory::class);
   $resourceStorage = $resourceFactory->getStorageObject(1);

   $subFolder = 'UploadedPhotos';
   if ($resourceStorage->hasFolder($subFolder) === false) {
       $resourceStorage->createFolder($subFolder);
   }
   $subFolderObject = $this->resourceStorage->getFolder($subFolder);
   $uploadedFile = $subFolderObject->addUploadedFile($file);
}
```

**Breaking it down:**

1. We instantiate the **ResourceFactory** so we can get the Storage
   where the files going to be uploaded to
2. We get the storage, for example the **fileadmin**, by its UID. I personally save the UID of the storage on the [extension settings](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html) and then [call](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationOptions/Index.html#accessing-saved-options) it wherever i want.
3. I always save the files to a subfolder so i first check if the folder exists. If not i create it. Then get the folder and save it in a variable.
4. Upload the file.

The function **addUploadedFile** accepts two arguments. First the file to be uploaded and the second is the Duplication behaviour. What it should do if the file already exists. By default, it cancels the upload. But you can either rename it, or replace it. So it would look like this:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\DuplicationBehavior;

$uploadedFile = $subFolderObject->addUploadedFile($file, DuplicationBehavior::REPLACE);
```

And that is it!

**Tipps:**

You can not always trust what comes from the client, so i would first save the files to a temp folder, check the **[CONTENT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php)** and not the extension of the file. Anyone could just rename a php file to file.png and still pass the extension validation (assuming that you check if the extension of the file is png or jpg etc). If everything checks out, you can just copy the files to the destination folder and delete the temp. You can find how to do that here: [Working with files](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#copying-a-file)

If you want to avoid/check duplication behaviour (if i am not wrong, the DuplicationBehaviour only checks the name but not the content), you can do it with two ways. First you read the content of the file and [generate a hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php) from it. Then you can check all the other files if they have the same hash. If i remember correctly, TYPO3 actually saves the file hash in the database, so in your File object you can validate if the saved hash is the same with the one you are about to upload. You can get the files like this:

```
if ($subFolderObject->getFileCount() > 0) {
  $files = $subFolderObject->getFiles();
  foreach ($files as $file) {
     // do something
   }
}
```

The second way it is just to rename the file to a random name (maybe timestamp plus something else) if you do not care if the same file is uploaded again. So you ll never have a duplication behaviour.

Hope it was helpful